# How do I use Visual Studio to edit my Microsoft Office scripts?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office, visual-studio-2013

I'm a frequent Visual C++ user working on some VBA scripts in MS Office 2010 and I would really like to be able to use Visual Studio 2013 (Professional) to edit them - is this possible? When I try to open my Access Database file from Visual Studio it just loads up in *Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.0* (ie. that horrible default IDE)...

What I'd really like is for it to open the module in VS when I click on the module in access. Can this be done?

Comment: The VBA editor is pretty lame compared to Visual Studio, but it does have benefits that you could not get with an external code editor: IntelliSense works well, with knowledge of all globals, all references included in the project, and in the case of code-behind-the-form/report, all the controls on the form/report. To numb the pain, I recommend installing MZ-Tools. It gives you global search/replace that the VBA editor lacks. I couldn't work without it.